# Is absolute value of an analytic function a harmonic function?

Tags: complex-analysis, absolute-value, harmonic-functions, analytic-functions

It is well known that if $f(x+i y) = u(x, y) + i v(x, y)$ is an analytic function of variable $z = x + iy$ then both $u$ and $v$ are harmonic functions.

Does $|f| = \sqrt{u^2 + v^2}$ have any special properties, in particular is $|f|$ harmonic?

Comment: Generally it's not harmonic, but it's subharmonic. $\log \lvert f\rvert$ is harmonic outside the zeros of $f$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Is there any smart way to show that $\log |f|$ is harmonic?

Comment: It's locally the real part of $\log f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generally not harmonic. For example let $f(z)=z$.
Then $\Delta |f|(z)=|z|^{-1},$ which is certainly not zero.

However, $\log |f|$ is harmonic if $f$ is analytic.

Comment: Thanks for that example, really simple one. There's just one typo: should be $\Delta |f(z)| = |z|^{-1}$ not $\Delta f(z) = |z|^{-1}$

Comment: @uranix Thanks, corrected.