# Find a complex analytic function equivalent to $|z-1|$ on a circle.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be the complex function $f(z) = |1-z|$ and let $C$ be the circle centered at the origin with radius 1. $f$ is not analytic at 1, but I'm trying to find a function $g$ which is analytic (on a domain containing $C$) and takes the same values on the curve $C$. That is to say, $f(z) = g(z)$ for all $z \in C$.

Intuitively $|1-z|$ represents the distance from $z$ to 1. When $z = 1$ this is 0, when $z = i$ this is $\sqrt 2$, and when $z = -1$ this is 2. It certainly behaves like $2\sin(x)$ as $z$ traces a path through the circle, but I don't see how to write that as a function of $z$.

For any given $z$ I know it has an argument and radius, so $z = re^{i\theta}$. And with that $\theta$, I could then do some trig and get an expression for $f(z)$. But it would be in terms of $\theta$ and I don't think that's legitimate, if we're looking for a function of $z$.

Anyone have any ideas?

[Edit: If it helps to clarify, $C$ here is the set of all points satisfying $|z|=1$.]

Comment: @CalvinKhor No, I mean "equivalent on the circle" not equivalent "to" the circle.  I make this more precise in the body of the post.

Comment: To clarify: you are looking for a function $f$ which is analytic on a neighborhood of the unit circle such that $f(e^{i\theta}) = |1-e^{i\theta}|$ for real $\theta$, right?

Comment: @MPW I think that's more or less right.  I've named $f$ to be the known function $|1-z|$ and named $g$ to be the function I'm searching for.  But yes, $g$ should be analytic on a domain containing the circle, and and satisfy the equation that you wrote for $f$.

Comment: Is that function anywhere analytic, at all? See, e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2333417/is-absolute-value-of-an-analytic-function-a-harmonic-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $|1-z|$ is not smooth (or even differentiable) at $z=1$ when restricted to this circle, so nor would be any function that extends it. Therefore there can be no such complex analytic function.

Comment: That's kind of what I suspected.  Would this change for $|1-z|^2$?  It also is not differentiable at 1, so the same logic applies, right?

Comment: This is not a valid argument. The function $g(z)=\overline{z}$ agrees with the function $f(z)= z$ on the line $\operatorname{Im} z = 0$, and $f$ is analytic on a neighborhood of that line, but $g$ is not analytic.

Comment: It definitely becomes smooth then. I think it should be extendible then but I’d need to consider it.

Comment: @MPW Note the clause (which I forgot to write at first) “when restricted to this circle”

Comment: The differentiability fails in the $y$ direction which luckily (or maybe unluckily) is the direction of tangency of the circle.

Answer (score 0):

As Funktoriality explained, one cannot do this in a neighbourhood of $1$, but can we
do this if we avoid $z=1$?

On the unit circle,
$$f(z)^2=|1-z|^2=(1-z)(1-\overline z)=(1-z)(1-z^{-1})=-\frac1z(1-z)^2.$$
Let's take then $g(z)$ to be $1-z$ times a suitable branch of $\sqrt{-1/z}$
defined on the complex plane slit along the positive real axis. This will give
a holomorphic extension of $f$ to a neighbourhood of $C-\{1\}$ which is
the best one can hope for.