# Finding a complex analytic function equivalent to $|1-z|^2$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z) = |1-z|^2$ and let $C$ be the circle of radius 1 centered at the origin.  I'm trying to find a complex function $g$ which is analytic on some domain which contains $C$, and which is equivalent to $f$ on $C$.  That is to say $f(z)=g(z)$ for all $z\in C$.

Note that I initially asked this: [Find a complex analytic function equivalent to $|z-1|$ on a circle.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3836863/find-a-complex-analytic-function-equivalent-to-z-1-on-a-circle)

I asked that in part because I was hoping that understanding $|1-z|$ might be enough for me to figure out $|1-z|^2$ on my own (and also partly out of mere curiosity).  But it turned out not to help and I'm still unable to find the function $g$ that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It holds $f(z) = z\bar{z}-z-\bar{z}+1 = 1-z-\frac{1}{z}+1$ for $z$ on the circle. This function is analytic everywhere except at $z = 0$.